# Deleting N lines from every start point

Tags: linux, perl, scripting

How would I delete the 6 lines starting from every instance of a word i see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this sed command will do what you want:

```
sed '/bar/,+5d' input.txt
```

It removes any line containing the text `bar` plus the five following lines.

Run as above to see the output. When you know it is working correctly use the switch `--in-place=.backup` to actually perform the change.

Comment: +1  OP should bear in mind that this deletes "front to back", that is, if `bar` appears within five lines following `bar`, that subsequent `bar` will be deleted before it has the chance to "define" six lines to delete.  Probably acceptable, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: - had an awk sniipet here - thought better of it.

Answer (score 3):

This simple perl script will remove every line that containts word "DELETE6" and 5 consecutive lines (total 6). It also saves previous version of file in FILENAME.bak. To run the script:

> perl script.pl FILE_TO_CHANGE

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $remove_count = 6;
my $word = "DELETE6";

local $^I = ".bak";
my $delete_count = 0;
while (<>) {
    $delete_count = $remove_count if /$word/; 
    print if $delete_count <= 0;
    $delete_count--;
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i.bak -n -e '$n ++; $n = -5 if /foo/; print if $n > 0' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print unless (/my_word/ and $n = 1) .. ++$n == 7'
```

Note that if `my_word` occurs in the skipped-over lines, the counter will not be reset.